# CMake can't find GLEW

Tags: cmake, glew

I've read this [1], but in my case CMake says it can't find glew.

I'm on Windows and there is a FindGLEW.cmake file in my CMake modules folder, presumably put there when I installed CMake-3.6.  I found GLEW on sourceforge and downloaded the zip file for Windows.  I unzipped and installed in C:\Program Files\glew.  When I've created my own libraries and used CMake to build and install them, this is the default location they are installed to so I am pretty confident I'm OK here.

The snippet from my CMakeLists.txt is:

```
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

The actual error message from CMake is:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find GLEW (missing: GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR GLEW_LIBRARY)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake:44 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  source/CMakeLists.txt:5 (find_package)
```

Is it possible the FindGLEW.cmake is broken?  I've looked at a couple of other FindXXXXX.cmake files and they are like snowflakes, each one pretty unique.  So it's hard for me to say with any certainty that it's following convention.

[1] [Linking GLEW with CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472813/linking-glew-with-cmake)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking in the [sources](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindGLEW.cmake), the package is looking for GLEW in relative paths. These relative paths are searched using different prefixes, including the content of the variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`:

- `<prefix>/include` for `find_path` which is used to find include directories.
- `<prefix>/lib` for `find_library` which is used to find libraries.

Assuming `C:/Program Files/glew/include` and `C:/Program Files/glew/lib` exist, add `C:/Program Files/glew` to your `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. Something like:

```
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Program Files/glew")
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
```

Note that the following lines:

```
include_directories(${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_libraries(${GLEW_LIBRARIES})
```

may be dropped using [imported target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#imported-targets) `Glew::Glew`:

```
add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo Glew::Glew)
```

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  Here's what I learned in addition to what you posted.  find_package doesn't recurse into subfolders beyond the normal folders it checks.  In my case, I edited CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to be C:\Program Files\glew.  This was needed.  But this just allows CMake to check CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH and subfolders named 'lib' and 'include' for .lib files and .h files, respectively.  The needed glew32s.lib file is buried in C:\Program Files\glew\lib\Release\x64\glew32s.lib.  After I made a copy of that .lib file in the lib folder the package was found.

Comment: Just one more note: had I used CMake to build glew from sources, I am confident it knows how to arrange the resulting package so that it is more easily found.  I think my troubles were more a result of a folder structure set up by sourceforge or whoever put together the zip file that I downloaded to get a precompiled version of glew.