# Clion with CMake can not see header files of OpenGL on MacOS

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, header-files, clion

I am trying to make a basic program in **C++** with **OpenGL** in **CLion**. I have installed **glew** by brew:

```
brew install glew
```

but **CLion** is not able to find it and giving me this error:

[image: Screenshot]

**CMakeLists.txt** file contains this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(untitled)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(untitled main.cpp)
```

How can I fix it ? Is it error in configuration of **CLion** or am I missing some packages ?

Thank you for help

Comment: You tag the question with "cmake", so you have probably written the `CMakeLists.txt` file. Show that file: exactly it determines where a compiler  searches headers and libraries.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for comment. I have fixed it up.

Comment: You should tell CMake (via `CMakeLists.txt` file) that your project uses GLEW libraries and headers. E.g., like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27487567/3440745).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. Know is GLEW ok, but <GL/gl.h> <GL/glu.h> is still red and throwing this:


    `/Users/John/CLionProjects/untitled/main.cpp:5:10: fatal error: 'GL/gl.h' file not found

    #include <GL/gl.h>

         ^~~~~~~~~

    1 error generated.
    make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/all] Error 2
   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/untitled.dir/rule] Error 2
   make: *** [untitled] Error 2`

Comment: GLEW, GL and GLU are *different* libraries. You should inform CMake about them separately (but in a similar way). So, technically, your problem can be divided into **3 separate problems**: 1. Use GL in a CMake project. 2. Use GLEW. 3. Use GLU. You may find information about each problem in different sources.