# Fatal Error: glew.h: No such file or directory when using make

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I'm attempting to build a `CMakeLists.txt` for my project. It needs to include SDL, OpenGL, and GLEW as well as all of my *.cpp and *.h files in different directories. *All files used to build the project are in the Project Source Directory that cmake is called in.*

The error:

```
In file included from /home/me/repos/AlchemyEngine/alchemy/alcEngine.cpp:1:0:
/home/me/repos/AlchemyEngine/alchemy/alcEngine.h:69:18: fatal error: glew.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glew.h>
```

I think it'd be easiest to show the steps for setting this project up in Visual Studio (which works as I used to develop from there) and hope I can get help recreating the setup in my CMakeLists.txt file.

Setting up the project in Visual Studio

```
1. Includes

Project -> *ProjectName* Properties -> VC++ Directories
Click Include Directories -> Click down-arrow- > edit

Browse for the include files (...\SDL2-OpenGL-GLEW-VC++\include)

2. Libraries

Project -> *ProjectName* Properties -> VC++ Directories
Click Library Directories -> Click down-arrow -> edit

Browse for the library files (...\SDL2-OpenGL-GLEW-VC++\lib)

3. Linkers

Project -> *ProjectName* Properties -> Linker -> Input
Click Additional Dependencies -> Click down arrow -> edit

Copy into box:
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib
SDL2_image.lib
OpenGL32.lib
glu32.lib
glew32.lib

4. DLLs

Build project with chosen entry point to create Debug folder with executable.

Copy the .dll files from the ...\SDL-OpenGL-GLEW-VC++\dropInExe folder and paste into the
Debug folder with the project executable
(...\*Project Folder*\Debug)
```

Here is my `CMakeLists.txt` file as it stands

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (AlchemyEngine)

set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

include_directories (
        alchemy/
        alchemy/event/
        alchemy/scene/
        alchemy/resource/
        alchemy/render/
        alchemy/util/
        game/
        #SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/include
)

set( srcs
        alchemy/alcEngine.cpp
        alchemy/event/alcEvent.cpp
        alchemy/render/alcRenderer.cpp
        alchemy/render/alcSprite.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcResource.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcShader.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcTexture.cpp
        alchemy/scene/alcObject.cpp
        alchemy/scene/alcScene.cpp
        alchemy/util/alcBlockAllocator.cpp
        alchemy/util/alcStackAllocator.cpp
        game/Player.cpp
        Main.cpp
)

add_library (libraries STATIC SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/include/)

add_executable (alc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${srcs})

target_link_libraries(alc libraries)

set_target_properties(libraries PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_target_properties(alc PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

After configuration and generation, `$CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR/build/bin` contains:

```
liblibraries.a  
glew32.dll  
libpng16-16.dll  
SDL2.dll  
SDL2_image.dll  
zlib1.dll
```

It seems to me that my method for including the header files is incorrect, but poking around the CMake documentation and other stack exchange posts hasn't produced any better results. I have a feeling it has to do with the linker step, but I cannot figure out how to specify the dependencies in CMake.

I can `tree` and post the output too if the project structure is that important for this issue.

**FINAL EDIT:**

The error was fixed in the answer below, here is my final CMakeLists.txt for anyone interested

```
# Outputs executable(s) in {PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin/

# specify min version and project name
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (AlchemyEngine)

# set output paths for binaries/executable
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/build/bin)
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})

# include project header files
include_directories (
        alchemy/
        alchemy/event/
        alchemy/scene/
        alchemy/resource/
        alchemy/render/
        alchemy/util/
        game/
)

# create source files definition
set( srcs
        alchemy/alcEngine.cpp
        alchemy/event/alcEvent.cpp
        alchemy/render/alcRenderer.cpp
        alchemy/render/alcSprite.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcResource.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcShader.cpp
        alchemy/resource/alcTexture.cpp
        alchemy/scene/alcObject.cpp
        alchemy/scene/alcScene.cpp
        alchemy/util/alcBlockAllocator.cpp
        alchemy/util/alcStackAllocator.cpp
        game/Player.cpp
        Main.cpp
)

# add a library target to be built from the source files
add_library (libraries STATIC SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/)
# specify include directories
target_include_directories(libraries PUBLIC SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/include/)
# specify libraries to use when linking the library
target_link_libraries (libraries 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/glew32.lib
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/glew32s.lib
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/SDL2_image.lib
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/SDL2.lib
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/lib/SDL2main.lib
)

# create the executable using the source files defined above
add_executable (alc ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/${srcs})
# specify the headers
target_include_directories(alc PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
# link the library to the project
target_link_libraries(alc libraries)

# force the linker language because there's some c stuff in the library files
set_target_properties(libraries PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
set_target_properties(alc PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

Comment: Do you want to **include directory** in CMake? - Look [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake). Do you want to work with glew library in an elegant way? Look [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472813/linking-glew-with-cmake).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I spent a few hours looking at the first link you posted earlier today, namely working with the `target_include_directories` and `target_link_libraries` for getting the library files set up right, but nothing worked same error.

Comment: I think my issue has less to do with glew specifically and more to do with the way my files are being linked/included. Looking at my `depend.make` shows that only my files are included -- none of the libraries are listed as dependencies.

Comment: Please, show your attempt when following the first question and the error you got. You current code is such ... a nonsence.

Comment: Did you remember to define `srcs` in the updated `CMakeLists.txt`?  Did you create a function called `main()`? Why are you setting the `LINKER_LANGUAGE`? CMake will usually figure out what to do unless you are overriding it for a reason.

Comment: @Fred Added srcs back and got the same error -- my mistake. 
My program does indeed have a main.
`LINKER_LANGUAGE` was set because my libraries include some c files and would throw an error regarding the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target_include_directories(libraries PRIVATE SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/include/)` should be using `PUBLIC` so that this path is known to any executable target that links against `libraries` such as `target_link_libraries(alc libraries)`.

This is assuming that `glew.h` resides in the `SDL2_OpenGL_GLEW_VC++/include/` directory.

Since `target_include_directories` is using a relative path (I'm pretty sure it is relative to the source tree) you need to make sure that this is correct for your directory tree.

Comment: Thank you that solved the `fatal error: glew.h: No such file or directory` issue! I had read about using `PRIVATE` but did not realize `PUBLIC` essentially does both `PRIVATE` and `INTERFACE`.